Will a nitro aryl resist an halogen exchange using nBuLi?
I would like to boronate 2-bromo-6-nitro-naphtalene using nBuLi and quenching with 2-Isopropoxy-4,4,5,5-tetramethyl-1,3,2-dioxaborolane. Since there is no alpha proton to the nitro, and that the nitro group is not known to be a strong DMG (Direct ortho metalation group), theory seems to be on my side. I would love to hear from anyone who has experience using nBuLi on nitroarenes or knows of other side reactions to be aware of!
Thank you

Sorry, but can you give a reference for a successful lithiation of a nitrocompound? I'm fairly certain that nitrogroup shall react.

I don't have any! Which is also why i am asking!

Aryl nitro groups will not stand lithiation conditions. The solution to your problem is a Pd catalysed Miyaura borylation between your substrate and pinacol borane.

Thanks! I am aware of the Miyaura borylation, but it doesn't work very well and the purification is annoying as Bpin and my compound have similar polarity. Nevertheless, do you have any ideas on why the nitro group won't stand ?

How about preparing the aryl magnesium by Knochel exchange and quenching with trimethyl borate?  See https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/anie.200300579

Also note: a colleague has advised me that you can do the Li-Hal exchange in the presence of nitro groups if you run with tBuLi at -100C

I tried to do the borylation using turbo grignard at -78C. After 45 min, a multitude of spots appeared on TLC. I will check the results today, and try the Li-Hal at -100!

What is the next proposed step for your product?

@TheRedManJolanBonelli Don't forget that a slow addition/cannulation can transfer the reagents/reagent solutions cooled -- possibly not perfectly $\pu{-78 ^\circ{}C}$, but significantly cooler than just by a brine/water ice bath.

@Waylander Next step is a very ugly suzuki coupling on two positions of a tetrabromo triphenyl compound. I will retry the miyaura borylation and try to remove the B2Pin2 using IBX or using high vacuum since no product formed using the turbo grignard (confirmed by using the product's TLC standard and ASPCI). If this doesn't work I will turn to using tBuLi.

@Buttonwood Thanks! It's true that I added the iPrMgCl (turbo grignard) dropwise from the bottle into the solution stirring at -78. I could try to cool both down to -78 and do a slow canula addition. However, I was working on a 10 mg scale so only a few drops were necessary which renders canula addition less efficient.

Further note, after doing the nBuLi reaction on a methoxy naphtalene, there is likely some moisture in the isopropoxy borane reagent which may be the cause of some problems. I have put it under 3A sieves to try to remove the moisture (If the isopropoxy borane is wet, I guess it slowly reacts to form isopropanol which also has a loose proton and will quench my reaction, buying a new bottle might also be my best bet). Thanks a lot for all the help!
